# Get rows with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my Postgres table:

**Table:**

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| sku  | properties      | value   |
|------+-----------------+---------|
| 1    | Family_ID       | 21      |
| 1    | Class_ID        | 21      |
| 2    | Family_ID       | 20      |
| 2    | Class_ID        | 21      |
| 3    | Family_ID       | 21      |
| 3    | Class_ID        | 21      |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

1. How to query if I want to fetch data where the `Family_ID` and `Class_ID` is `21`.

**The expected return value:**

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| sku  | properties      | value   |
|------+-----------------+---------|
| 1    | Family_ID       | 21      |
| 1    | Class_ID        | 21      |
| 3    | Family_ID       | 21      |
| 3    | Class_ID        | 21      |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

2. How to query if I want to fetch data where the `Family_ID` is `20` and `Class_ID` is `21`.

**The expected return value:**

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| sku  | properties      | value   |
|------+-----------------+---------|
| 2    | Family_ID       | 20      |
| 2    | Class_ID        | 21      |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?. This is pretty straight forward

Comment: on second thoughts it may not be the very conventional data model to query data from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select sku
from tablename
group by sku
having 
  max(case when properties = 'Family_ID' then value end) = 21
  and
  max(case when properties = 'Class_ID' then value end) = 21
```

returns all the `sku`s that satisfy your conditions and you can use it with the operator `IN` like this:

```
select * from tablename
where sku in (
  select sku
  from tablename
  group by sku
  having 
    max(case when properties = 'Family_ID' then value end) = 21
    and
    max(case when properties = 'Class_ID' then value end) = 21
)
```

You could also use MAX() window function:

```
select t.sku, t.properties, t.value
from (
  select *,
    max(case when properties = 'Family_ID' then value end) over (partition by sku) family_id,
    max(case when properties = 'Class_ID' then value end) over (partition by sku) class_id
  from tablename  
) t  
where t.family_id = 21 and t.class_id = 21
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6023dc1dba94887536135267777b5118).
Results:

```
> sku | properties | value
> --: | :--------- | ----:
>   1 | Family_ID  |    21
>   1 | Class_ID   |    21
>   3 | Family_ID  |    21
>   3 | Class_ID   |    21
```

Answer (score 1):

To operate across rows you need to group, but the easiest thing here (given that you seem like you will want ever more variations of this theme) is probably to pivot your data:

```
WITH x as(
 SELECT f.sku, c.value as class_value, f.value as family_value
 FROM
  (select sku, value FROM table WHERE properties = 'family_id') f
  INNER JOIN
  (select sku, value FROM table WHERE properties = 'class_id') c
  ON f.sku = c.sku
)
```

You can now use a WHERE clause like normal:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE family_value = 20 and class_value = 21
```

If you need the data back in a column format, you can unpivot it again:

```
SELECT
  sku,
  'family_id' as properties,
  family_value as value
FROM 
  x

UNION ALL

SELECT
  sku,
  'class_id' as properties,
  class_value as value
FROM 
  x
```

But it might be easier to just work with the data in its pivoted form.

I wouldn't necessarily do this myself, but its a lot easier to understand this form of pivoting if you're used to regular joining, union and other similar "typical" database operations, so I'm recommending this as you may well find it easier to maintain and extend. Conditional aggregation to do a pivot is potentially more efficient but more complex to maintain:

```
WITH X as (
  SELECT
    sku,
    MAX(CASE WHEN properties = 'Family_ID' THEN value END) as family_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN properties = 'Class_ID' THEN value END) as class_value
  FROM
    table
  GROUP BY sku
)
```

The CASE WHENs spread the `value`s across columns according to the `properties` value. The group by/max then collapse the rows removing the nulls leaving you with a unique sku and the values in named columns according to what kind of value they are

Answer (score 1):

```
--case 1
select *
  from tbl t
where exists (select *
                from tbl t1 
               where t1.sku=t.sku
                 and t1.properties='Family_ID'
                 and t1.value=21)
  and exists (select *
                from tbl t1 
               where t1.sku=t.sku
                 and t1.properties='Class_ID'
                 and t1.value=21)



--case 2
select *
  from tbl t
where exists (select *
                from tbl t1 
               where t1.sku=t.sku
                 and t1.properties='Family_ID'
                 and t1.value=20)
  and exists (select *
                from tbl t1 
               where t1.sku=t.sku
                 and t1.properties='Class_ID'
                 and t1.value=21)
```